# Why are form field suggestions out of position in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, forms, dropdownlist

For a year or more I've had a problem with Chrome, always on the latest versions, where the suggestions dropdown is out of position. I've reset Chrome. I've disabled all extensions. Nothing resolves the issue. The problem occurs on a variety of websites. My OS is Windows 10/64.

[image]

[image]

One oddity is that if I click the input a third time (once to focus, once for suggestions, and one more), the dropdown jumps to its correct position.

Comment: Do you have any third-party software installed that can manipulate windows' position? Also, is the position of the popup always at the same location? or is its position always relevant to the location of the input field?

Comment: I can't think of anything in terms of other software. I'm a web software engineer and have a pretty good handle on what I'm using. Location is not always the same. OS is Windows 10/64.

Comment: Are you using a HiDPI screen and your screen scaling is higher than 100%?

Comment: Oh! I think you're onto something there. Chrome's dev tools opens huge on my wing monitors, too.